# Laravel: Validation alpha and regex pattern on update

Tags: php, laravel, validation, exception, laravel-6

Hello all this is my update controller for an user. I want to know how can I apply these laravel validation rules ONLY to updated fields. Currently when I update only the first name, mobile number also get validated. My name fields are alpha validated and phone number is validated via regex.

```
public function update(Request $request, User $setting)
    {
         request()->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
            'mobile'=>['required', 'string','regex:/\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|
            2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|
            4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)\d{1,14}$/'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email,'.$setting->id.''],
        ]);

        $setting->update($request->all());


                        return Redirect::back()->with('success','User updated successfully');                
    }
```

I able to handle the email(unique) field, but not the others.

Comment: What do you mean by updating only the first name? You send only the first name to request?

Comment: Basically, if you succeeded to create the model then it means that the validation passed right? Why wouldn't it pass on update too?

Comment: no assume there are four fields, first name,last name email and mobile number, then assume user updates one of the mentioned fileds, then I want only that field to be validated not the unchanged fields.

Comment: But, even if they are validated, they will pass the validation since they passed it on creation..

Comment: yes but the issue is i have inserted some values to the db manually (without considering the validation rules) so they have not been validated at the creation

Comment: well, that's a reason :) that should never happen..

Comment: yeah, if you can give me a solution to validate only the changed filed, that would be a great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the small chat we had in the comments, what you must do is to first get the model from the database and to diff the request with the model's attributes. Then you can keep the validation rules for the changed attributes only.

```
public function update(int $id, Request $request, User $userRepository)
{    
     $user = $userRepository->find($id);

     $changedAttributes = array_diff($request->all(), $user->getAttributes());

     $validationRules = array_intersect_key([
        'name'      => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
        'mobile'    => ['required', 'string', 'regex:/\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|
        2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|
        4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)\d{1,14}$/'],
        'email'     => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email,'.$setting->id.''],
    ], $changedAttributes);

    $this->validate($request, $validationRules);

    $user->update($changedAttributes);

    return Redirect::back()->with('success','User updated successfully');                
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it give me following error, Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given called in C:\xampp\htdocs\myWeb\app\Http\Controllers\SettingController.php on line 70 which is $this->validate($validationRules, $changedAttributes);

Comment: yw :) glad i could help